# Poker game in Python, making the turns

Tags: python, poker

I'm writing a poker game and I'm having trouble creating a function for turns where one player can raise, then another player call then raise again, followed by another (etc). I'm not sure how to organize this. I have this so far:

```
def turn(playerBank,label):
    #playerBank is just the player's balance (whoever's turn it is) and label is just  tkinter text.
    win.getMouse()
    action = ent.getText()
    if action == 'check':
        pass
    elif action == 'call':
        playerBank = playerBank - cashMoney
        pool = pool + cashMoney
    elif action == 'raise':
        cashMoney = cash.getText()
        playerBank = playerBank - cashMoney
        pool = pool + cashMoney
    elif action == 'fold':
         break
```

How would i make it two turns (one per player) but then, if a player raises, allow it to loop AGAIN so that the other player has the option to call or fold... etc.?

Comment: My suggestion? Keep track of the total bets everyone has put in and the maximum total so far and just loop indefinitely until you get to a player whose total is exactly the max. Everyone else has to either call/raise/fold. You could also track whether everyone has had one turn or not (to deal with blind ante situations).

Comment: What's the 'maximum' total?

Comment: The highest bet so far. In a game with a small and big blind, that value starts at the big blind (if no blinds, start at zero). Then change that value when a raise or initial bet happens. Repeatedly loop through your players until you reach one who hadn't folded whose total bet is equal to that maximum. That means no need for them to call/raise/fold.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to mind is to use booleans. Make a function that checks if the turn is completely over and make another boolean to check whether a player has raised or not.

Boolean playerRaise would be false until a player raises, and turns true only when all the players have responded to the raise. You can check that by using the number of players and measuring how many responses there were. This resets every time a player raises.

Function checkTurn would just check if playerRaise has become false because if its false then we know for sure the turn has been finished.

I'm just thinking out loud here, but it seems to be a plausible solution, what do you think?

Comment: That does sound good. However, lets say the first player raises. Then, the second players calls and raises as well. Now, I have to get the first player's response. And this could loop for a while, so I'm not sure where i can go.

Comment: First player raises -> playRaise = true | checkTurn() -> it loops because playRaise = true | Second player raises -> playRaise = true + resets number of players to respond | checkTurn() -> it loops because playRaise = true       I think the loop works if thats what you're asking...?